# What could be a dictionary approved, synonymous alternative for 'intentful'?

Tags: single-word-requests

In sentence:

"I was *intentful* on the completion of the work today."

I'd thought of using the following sentence too:

"I was desirous about completing the work today."

But, it doesn't sound as appropriate to me, as it wasn't merely a desire or a wish that was being harbored, but the thought was more toward the ambition. The more proper and correct term, intent, suggested by a commenter, does seem usable. But, it still feels lacking, as it's too infested with intention to me. Like, it emphasizes more toward the intention?

Supplementary:
**Desire** vs ***Intentful*** -- as I distinguish:
The former would be just a wish a person would hold, while *Intentful* may lean more toward sketching a methodology into achieving one's goal.

Comment: What have you found in a dictionary?

Comment: Look at the second subsense of the adjective M-W gives [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intent).

Comment: ***intentful*** isn't a word. You were [***intent** on **completing**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intent+on+completing%2Cintent+on+the+completion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintent%20on%20completing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintent%20on%20the%20completion%3B%2Cc0) the work*.

Comment: Either _intent on completing_ as FumbleFingers suggests, or _determined to complete_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Then why this graph - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intentful&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintentful%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cintentful%3B%2Cc0?

Comment: @Justin: What can I say? Sure - the "word" is regularly-formed, but it's not listed in the full OED. And whereas ***my*** link above shows at least a few instances of ***intent on the completion*** (dwarfed by instances of ***intent on completing***), if I try to include ***intentful** on the completion / completing*, neither of them occur often enough to chart. Obviously it's just a matter of opinion whether ***intentful*** is "a word" or not, but I'm siding with the OED on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it. 
I’d use “I had hoped to complete the work today.”
I’m not grasping your problem with ‘intent’ or ‘intended’ and the distinction you’re making between hope, what you planned, desired and ‘ambition.’

But if it matters to you, just say it: “It was my ambition to complete the work today;” or “my intent and ambition was to complete the work today.” Most readers won’t notice the redundancy.

American Heritage, the OED and M-W all define ‘ambition’ by using the word ‘desire.’
M-W list of synonyms for ambition also includes: aim, aspiration, goal, intent, intention, object, objective, plan, and target.

Comment: I do not know, if it'd make more sense, but it was written in the sense that the job was thought to be done, just not with that kind of enthusiasm, I suppose -- to use _intent_ or _determined_.

Comment: @Bao Norbert is right to suggest (though not in so many words) that to express at simple thought, attitude or action in so abstract a way is  unnecessarily laboured.  A verb is generally stronger than the copula with a cognate adjective.  “I had hoped / intended... “ is much better that the original.  But you could say “I had been ‘intent’ on ...”. That is because being intent on is stronger than just intending, paradoxical as that might sound.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for the description you've provided could be **hell-bent.**

> Impetuously or recklessly determined to do or achieve something: *was hell-bent on winning.*

[AHD]

*I was hell-bent on completing the work today. (And I have!)*